Why Email not being sent with NextJS server actions with Resend.com?
I have a NextJS 13.5.1 and have enabled server actions, project where I try to submit a form that should send an email using server actions and resend. I have copy and pasted a curl snippet which worked and had sent the email, but it doesn't work in the app.
packages/landing/src/containers/AgencyFormal/ContactUs/index.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  FormWrapper,
  Heading,
  Form,
  Row,
  FormField,
  RequiredLabel,
  Input,
  Button,
  Label,
  Textarea,
} from "./contactUs.style";
import { sendEmail } from '@/../actions/sendEmail';

const ContactUs = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await sendEmail({ name, email, message });
    console.log("Sending...")

    if (result.success) {
      console.log("Success")
      setStatus('Email sent successfully!');
      setName('');
      setEmail('');
      setMessage('');
    } else {
      setStatus(result.error);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Heading>Connect with Our Team of Experts</Heading>
      <FormWrapper>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Row>
            <FormField>
              <RequiredLabel htmlFor="name">Full Name</RequiredLabel>
              <Input
                type="text"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                placeholder="John Doe"
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                value={name}
                required
              />
            </FormField>
            <FormField>
              <RequiredLabel htmlFor="email">Email</RequiredLabel>
              <Input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="doe@email.com"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                value={email}
                required
              />
            </FormField>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <FormField>
              <RequiredLabel htmlFor="phone">Phone</RequiredLabel>
              <Input
                type="tel"
                id="phone"
                name="phone"
                placeholder="+1 555 123 4567"
                required
              />
            </FormField>
            <FormField>
              <Label htmlFor="website">Website</Label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                id="website"
                name="website"
                placeholder="yourwebsite.com"
              />
            </FormField>
          </Row>
          <FormField>
            <RequiredLabel htmlFor="message">Message</RequiredLabel>
            <Textarea
              id="message"
              name="message"
              placeholder="How can I help you?"
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              value={message}
              required
            />
          </FormField>
          <Button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
            {isLoading ? 'Sending...' : 'Submit'}
          </Button>
          {status && <p>{status}</p>}
        </Form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ContactUs;


packages/landing/src/actions/sendEmail.js
import { Resend } from 'resend';


export async function sendEmail(data) {
  'use server';
  const { name, email, message } = data;
  const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_KEY);

  try {
    await resend.emails.send({
      from: "anitadd@gmail.com",
      to: ['bobby@gmail.com'],
      subject: 'Contact form submission',
      text: "This is website",
    });
    console.log("try")
    return { success: true };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    return { error: 'Failed to send email' };
  }
}


I get this error when I run it locally, even if I pass the API key
{
statusCode: 401,
message: "Missing API Key",
name: "missing_api_key"
}


try to log send result. there might be a warning which can not catch by try catch block.

The 'user server' directive should be at the start of the sendEmail.js file. Using it inside of a function only works when the action is used in a server component iirc

I updated the question. I get this error which doesn't make sense since I pass the API key correctly. {
statusCode: 401,
message: "Missing API Key",
name: "missing_api_key"
}
